# Gnome shell cannot detect opened window for some system application

Tags: gnome-terminal, gedit, gnome-shell

Assume I search `firefox` in `gnome-shell` and hit enter to open. But when I search `firefox` again and hit enter it will brought the `firefox` window to front because it's already opened.

But this behavior is not working for `gnome-terminal` and `gedit` (maybe some other apps too). For `terminal` it opens new window every time. And for `gedit`, creates new tab.

I reinstall `gnome-terminal` and `gedit` and noticed they create multiple `.desktop` files. One named `gedit.desktop` and other is `org.gnome.Gedit.desktop`. Some system apps also follow the same pattern i.e `Gnome-terminal, Totem, Software & updates` etc.

Can someone explain the reason? Or is it a bug and which `process` is responsible?

How can I fix the  behavior of `gedit` and `gnome-terminal`? Manually deleting the `.desktop` file named `org.gnome.*` helps but it restore after any upgrade.

Comment: I guess it's a bug but not sure which process is responsible for. So I report two separate bug and workaround for gnome-terminal and gedit

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1739263

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1739264